# color error with marginpar in classicthesis

Tags: color, classicthesis, marginpar

I have reduced my problem to this short document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
Consideriamo un esempio.
\marginpar{nota}
\end{document}
```

which, in my installation, produces the following error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Black'.
```

Cannot understand how to fix this. Here is the complete log: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwkxkVFUbSmjM2hCQm8zMUZsLTA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classicthesis.sty` already loads the package xcolor for you,  with this option:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
```

Just remove the call to `xcolor` from your document and it will work.

Comment: Nice diagnosis!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason a package wanted to use a color named `Black`, which is not the standard defined color, `black`.  Thus, I just created the color `Black` using a `\colorlet{}{}`and all are happy.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{Black}{black}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\begin{document}
Consideriamo un esempio.
\marginpar{nota}
\end{document}
```